# AltoRouter redirect to show Twig Template

Tags: php, twig, altorouter

I'm using AltoRouter with Twig Template. My index.php is

**index.php**

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->map('GET','/', function(){
     require __DIR__ . '/views/index_v.php';
}, 'inicio');   

$router->map('GET','/historia', function(){
     require __DIR__ . '/views/historia_v.php';
}, 'historia');

$match = $router->match();

if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {               
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params']); 
} else {
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

It works perfectly, but I'd like to change my index.php to use the $match['name'] or another parameter to call, for example a redirect.php

**index.php (changed)**

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->map('GET','/', /views/redirect.php', 'inicio');    
$router->map('GET','/historia', /views/redirect.php', 'historia');  

$match = $router->match();

if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {               
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params']); 
} else {
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

**redirect.php**

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array('views', 'includes', 'includes/languages/en', 'includes/languages/es', 'includes/languages/it', 'includes/languages/zh'));

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

include('includes/languages/'.idioma().'/comunes.php'); 
include('includes/languages/'.idioma().'/historia.php');    

if($match['name'] == 'inicio'){
    echo $twig->render('inicio.php', array('textos'=>$textos['idioma']));   
}elseif($match['name'] == 'historia'){
    echo $twig->render('historia.php', array('textos'=>$textos['idioma'], 'historia'=>$historia['idioma']));
}
```

My idea is to use a single redirect.php file that shows one or another Twit Template

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with a single index.php

**index.php**

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->map('GET','/', /views/inicio.php', 'inicio.php');    
$router->map('GET','/historia', /views/historia.php', 'historia.php');  

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array('views', 'includes', 'includes/languages/en', 'includes/languages/es', 'includes/languages/it', 'includes/languages/zh'));

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

include('includes/languages/'.idioma().'/comunes.php'); 

$match = $router->match();

if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {               
    echo $twig->render($match['name'], array('textos'=>$textos['idioma']));
} else {
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```